# Delphi Access Violation when moving button on form

Tags: delphi, button, access-violation

I am trying to move 2 buttons on the form using a while loop checking for the buttons left property, but I have an Access Violation. I am exeting the procedure with CreateThread()

```
The code:

procedure AnimButton1();
var ImageCount: integer;
var b1, b2: integer;
begin

  try

       while (b2 <> 187) do
       begin
           b2 := frmNotification.btnBuzina2.Left;
           frmNotification.btnBuzina2.Left := b2 - 1;

       end;

       while (b1 <> 256) do
       begin
           b1 := frmNotification.btnBuzina.Left;
           frmNotification.btnBuzina.Left := b1 - 1;

       end;

  except;
  end;

end;
```

BUT, when I use a Sleep() with at least 5 miliseconds, I dont have an access violation, like this:

```
procedure AnimButton1();
var ImageCount: integer;
var b1, b2: integer;
begin

  try

       while (b2 <> 187) do
       begin
           b2 := frmNotification.btnBuzina2.Left;
           frmNotification.btnBuzina2.Left := b2 - 1;
           Sleep(5);
       end;

       while (b1 <> 256) do
       begin
           b1 := frmNotification.btnBuzina.Left;
           frmNotification.btnBuzina.Left := b1 - 1;
           Sleep(5);
       end;

  except;
  end;

end;
```

Could someone help me to find out why without the sleep I get the access violation and with it I dont?

thx in advance!

Comment: You have omitted to initialise b1 and b2 before testing their values with the "while ..."s.  They will have random values on entry to AnimButton1.

Comment: Please tell us the exact message of the occuring exception and mark the line in your code above to show where your code breaks.

Comment: The exception is http://prntscr.com/7emu4e
Occurs inside the while before 'end;'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I am executing the procedure with `CreateThread()`.

That is your problem. VCL code must only be called from the main UI thread. Use `TThread.Synchronize` to invoke the VCL code on the main thread.

That said, a timer might be a more appropriate solution to you problem than a thread.

Comment: perhaps his main thread is busy in some long operation, so he tried to fix it wrong way., instead of offloading the long operation into an aux thread, he tried to offset main user UI there.

Comment: That said, I believe he can move the button from the aux thread using Windows GDI layer, still if his VCLMainThread is locked in some long calculations, it would fail to do WM_PAINT in timely manner

Comment: Using the timer the main thread freezes and only unfreeze when the full process is over. I think I really need a thread running outta the main thread.

Comment: That's because you are doing all the work in the main UI thread. You need to put the long running task in the worker thread, and handle the UI in the UI thread. For which a timer is fine.

Comment: The timer is still locking the interface while the action is being executed. Even if I put a sleep().

Comment: As I said, you have the long running task in the main UI thread. Which means that the message pump is not being serviced. Anyway, I answered the question that you asked. Please don't ask me to debug and fix the rest of your program which I cannot and am having to guess as to its make up.